# VB.NET How to test my app under different resolutions?

Tags: vb.net, windows, testing, resolution

As title say, how I can test my windows application under different resolutions? I'm bored to ask my friend for team viewer everytime when I want to test my application to see how it does his actions and looks anchored in a smaller resolution than mine.

Comment: Switch the resolution on your machine?  Run a Windows VM where you can switch resolutions?

Comment: Maybe you should create [resolution independent forms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182070) in you application

Comment: I guess I'll run a windows in virtual machine. But it take so much time and resources of my bad computer, if you have any alternatives just tell me guys. :)

Comment: Oh... I just had to switch the resolution on my machine. Why no one told me that? :)